# What is Archive field in Release file used for?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

For example current [Release file](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Release) for Wheezy is following:

```
Archive: stable
Origin: Debian
Label: Debian
Version: 7.1
Component: main
Architecture: amd64
```

Now I can't find description of this Archive field neither on [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat#A.22Release.22_files) page or anywhere else using Google.  I have noticed though, that the content is similar to what the page says about "Suite" field, whereas the Suite field is missing.

What is this field used for?  Is it just a newer/older naming for Suite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Release` file you refer to is only for backward-compatibility. As you have guessed, its `Archive` field is equal to the `Suite` field.

Nowadays, another [Release file (.../dists/wheezy/Release)](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release) is used. It has the `Suite` field and additionally a detached signature (`Release.gpg`).

Comment: Nice and clear.  BTW, do you know when this format has been obsoleted?

Comment: End of 2003, there were some related changes made for `apt` 0.6.x. See the [apt changelog](http://ftp-master.metadata.debian.org/changelogs/main/a/apt/unstable_changelog) for details.